# Inline math spacing and varying interword spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, inline

Say I want to reduce the space between two letters in math mode by 2/18 quad. Going all Die Hard 3, I put together 2 -3/18 quad `\!` and add 4/18 quad with `\:`. The problem is, though, that apparently the positive space gets squashed according to the current line's interword spacing while the negative space does not. So in extreme cases I get -6/18 quad which looks less than satisfying in my MWE and in the real world:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\newcommand{\md}{\ensuremath{M\!\!\:D}}
\begin{document}
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a $\md$ a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa $\md$ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
\end{document}
```

So why is inline math subjected to normal interword spacing adjustments and how can I switch it off? (I can imagine this leading to problematic results in many formulae, even when not doing such strange spacing arithmetic as I did.)

Comment: I guess that the math spaces `\quad` or ` \!` or others are rubber spaces. Try to use `\mbox{\ensuremath{M\!\!\:D}}`.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks for the alternative approach. Just for the record, I had experimented a bit and `\!` does not actually appear to be a rubber space, only `\:` is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some glue in `\:`, but not in `\!`: the first uses `\medmuskip` which is `4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu`, the second `\thinmuskip` which is `3.0mu`.  To avoid the glue use only `\!` or, simpler, just `\mkern`:

[image: Sample output]

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\newcommand{\md}{\ensuremath{M\mkern-9mu D}}
\begin{document}
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a $\md$ a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa $\md$ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa

\clearpage
\hbox{aa aa $\md$ aa aa}

\hbox spread 10pt{aa aa $\md$ aa aa}

\hbox spread 20pt{aa aa $\md$ aa aa}

\end{document}
```

As `18mu = 1em` this is much closer spacing than you ask for, use `-2mu` instead.

The numbers in my statements above come from:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( \show\!\show\: \)
\showthe\thinmuskip
\showthe\medmuskip
\end{document}
```

which prints the following infomation in the log file:

```
> \!=macro:
->\mskip -\thinmuskip .
l.10 \( \show\!
               \show\: \)
> \:=macro:
->\mskip \medmuskip .
l.10 \( \show\!\show\:
                       \)
> 3.0mu.
l.11 \showthe\thinmuskip

> 4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu.
l.12 \showthe\medmuskip
```

As far as I can see, in standard latex, the glued skips `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`, are only used around binary and relation symbols, and in the definition of `\bmod`.

Comment: How to use those last commands on your code?

Comment: @Sigur I have now explained this in my answer.

Comment: OK. It works. I can see the code on the log file. But I don't know why my TeXstudio returns error when I compile it. Thanks.

Comment: It is the `\show` command that is causing `TeXstudio` to think there is an error.  When you run tex interactively, `\show` will stop the processing at that point, display its output, and prompt for a command.  `Texstudio`, and other systems, run tex in nonstopmode, carrying on past such prompts.

Comment: Ok, so 1mu is 1/18 quad, right? `\mkern` is exactly the command I needed. Just for the record, for -2/18 quad I need a kerning of -2mu, not -9. Thanks!

Comment: @sigur I have now split these `\show` commands off into a separate file for clarity.

Comment: @Christian Yes.  I have now added that information to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just tell TeX to add -2/18 of an em. If the command is to be used in text, do

```
\newcommand{\md}{\textit{M\kern-0.11111em D}}
```

A kern will never be stretched or shrinked.

Load also `amsmath` to use it both in text and math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\md}{\textit{M\kern-0.11111em D}}

\begin{document}
a a a a a a \md{} a a a a a

a a a a a a $\md$ a a a a a

\end{document}
```

The little difference is due to the fact that the italic correction is applied in text mode, but not in math mode.

[image]

Comment: if there's a reason to use the `cmmi` letters rather than `\textit` the `\kern` could be expressed instead as `\mkern-2mu`.